# server error using URI embedded images in a required file if index.php isn't in the url

Tags: php, html

Struggling. Help!

In index.php:

```
require "cachedPages/home.html";
```

If I visit: https://websiteaddress.org/index.php then it works fine.

If I visit: https://websiteaddress.org then I get an internal server error.

I guess it's a .htaccess thing. All I have in there is some cpanel php72 code and:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

It seems there's some difference between how index.php is called if you call it directly as opposed to .htaccess calling it for you?!?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's something about the specific cachedPages/home.html file that is causing the server error if called in this way. It works fine with other files in that folder. Investigating...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have one of the following options in your .htaccess then Apache won't know which file to default back to:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
FallBackResource /index.php
```

Also I'd recommend installing mod_rewrite as well.  It's handy for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've managed to sort the problem, but it's a pretty weird situation that no-one else will probably ever experience. Here goes...

If the user lands at:
https://websiteaddress.org rather than https://websiteaddress.org/index.php
and that page (php) requires another page,
which has images that are embedded as URIs rather than linked src files.

Then, the first URI causes a server error.

If I replace the

```
img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,/998a9g98ahg...etc'
```

with

```
img src='path/to/file.jpg'
```

on the first instance of a jpg then it all works fine.
All the later URIs are fine, it's just the first instance!

It all works now, with this workaround; and the situation is so unique and bizarre that I doubt this thread will be of use to anyone else. In fact it's so edge-case that I can't be bothered investigating it any further myself.